# Why I'm getting string instead of JSON array?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm sending POST request to the server. I'm expecting JSON array of articles in return but I'm getting just string instead of JSON data in response body.

PHP script which I'm using to return in response:

```php
echo $MyArticles = array (
 array("articleName1","count1","link1"),
 array("articleName2","count2","link2"),
 array("articleName3","count3","link3"),
 array("articleName4","count4","link4"),
 array("articleName5","count5","link5") 
);
```

Here is my js script:

```js
$.get("../getArticles.php",
{
    userid: user
},
function(data, status){
    var objData = JSON.parse(data); //error happens there
});
```

Here is the response which I'm getting:

[image: just string]

Error:

[image]

What is the proper way to return JSON data?

Comment: What part is PHP... or what part "doesn't work"? Is `data` populated?

Comment: First of all you should use `console.log(data);` and show us the result .. Also you should provide your php code in `getArticles.php`, like comment above said.

Comment: The PHP code should use something like `echo json_encode($data);`. And make sure it doesn't produce any other output other than this. You can use the Network tab in the browser to see everything that it's returning.

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm
````php
echo $MyArticles = array
(
 array("articleName1","count1","link1"),
 array("articleName2","count2","link2"),
 array("articleName3","count3","link3"),
 array("articleName4","count4","link4"),
 array("articleName5","count5","link5")
);
````

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm
data is not taken from server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) when you return data from php to JS, here is example based on your code:

**JS:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
                $.post("../../pos/getArticles.php",
                {
                    userid: 1
                },
                function(data, status){
                    var objData = JSON.parse(data);
                    $.each(objData, function( key, val ) { // get arrays
                        console.log(val[0], val[1], val[2]);
                    });
                    //for (i in objData){
                    //    objData[i][0] = "<td><a href='"+objData[i][2]+"'>"+objData[i][0]+"</a></td>";
                    //}
                    //addDataToArticles(objData);
                    // alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$MyArticles = array (
 array("articleName1","count1","link1"),
 array("articleName2","count2","link2"),
 array("articleName3","count3","link3"),
 array("articleName4","count4","link4"),
 array("articleName5","count5","link5") 
);

echo json_encode($MyArticles); exit;
```

You can run this code and check console, this row `console.log(val[0], val[1], val[2])` returns you all data you want and you can use as you wish.

In this code it returns:

```
articleName1 count1 link1
articleName2 count2 link2
articleName3 count3 link3
articleName4 count4 link4
articleName5 count5 link5
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP just returns it's type, because PHP doesn't know what todo with array itself. So you have to encode your data to JSON format (which is string) with `json_encode()` function before returning with `echo`. Then PHP easily writes down that JSON string in response body.